# How to remove matched string in a word through inux

Tags: linux, jenkins

I want to remove "pull-request" from string/word ($JOB_NAME)
and the string is not fixed may changes based Jenkins job name.

e.g.: terraform-jenkins-pull-request,
terraform-jenkins-test-pull-request
terraform-jenkins-vertex-a-pull-request
And here the string is not fixed but "pull-request" word will come at last every time.

Expected output: terraform-jenkins,terraform-jenkins-test..etc.

Answer (score 0):

echo "terraform-jenkins-pull-request" | sed 's/-pull-request//g'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).